# What does the "leak period" mean in sonarQube?

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I'm new in SonarQube I started reading documentation but a lot of time a found **"The leak period"** but I didn't found anything about it can someone explain me what it means.

Comment: I answered the "leak period" part of your question, please post separate question about sonar-runner (or try to search one first, there are some good answers around)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Shortly, leak period is time frame (usually since last release), where specified criteria are measured on newly added code. This allows to focus on quality of fresh code and stop the accumulation of technical debt.

The "leak" concept is explained in documentation here https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Fixing+the+Water+Leak

---

**Update**
SonarSource has fleshed-out and updated the terminology / philosophy: https://sonarqube.org/features/clean-as-you-code.

Answer (score 8):

While [SonarQube's documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Fixing+the+Water+Leak) does an adequate job explaining the theory, code.scan (sonarqube for salesforce code) does a great job [explaining the scenarios](https://docs.codescan.io/hc/en-us/articles/360011880472-SonarQube-Leak-Periods).

> How the Leak Period is set determines what issues are displayed as
>   ‘new’ issues. There are several options for this.
>
> **Date**
>
> By entering a date in the format yyyy-MM-dd, SonarQube will show
>   the issues that have arisen since that date.
>
> **Number of days**
>
> By entering a single number, SonarQube will show the
>   issues that have arisen since that number of days ago. Keep in mind
>   that the issues found in the last 5 days will not be the same a week
>   from now.
>
> **Previous version**
>
> By using the `previous_version` setting, the Leak
>   Period will be tracked from the previous version set with the
>   `sonar.projectVersion` parameter.
>
> For example, a scan is run on a project with the `sonar.projectVersion`
>   set to `1.0` . After time, the project's `sonar.projectVersion` is set to `1.1`. The Leak Period set to previous_version would display all issues that
>   have arisen since sonar.projectVersion 1.0 .
>
> **Specific version**
>
> By entering your projects required
>   `sonar.projectVersion`, the Leak Period will display all issues that
>   have arisen since that specific version.
>
> For example, a scan is run on a project with the `sonar.projectVersion` set to
>   `BASELINE`. The project’s `sonar.projectVersion` is then set to
>   `DEVELOPMENT` and all necessary scans are run over time. The Leak Period
>   set to `BASELINE` would display all issues that have arisen since the
>   original scan.
>
> It is important to note that all violations, when they were introduced
>   and the version they are introduced in are tracked. The Leak Period
>   only filters this information on the project’s Overview dashboard and
>   the Issues screen.